# Disabling AMD cpu boost on 22.04?

Tags: cpu, amd-ryzen, turbo-boost

I previously ran 21.04 on my Asus PN51 (AMD Ryzen 7 5700U) and could disable boost by setting /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost to '0' (described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/boost.txt)). However after upgrading to 22.04 it does not seem to have any effect anymore, which seems a bit strange.

Has this functionality changed somehow lately, and if so, how do I disable AMD boost?

Comment: I wonder if you are now using the new AMD pstate CPU frequency scaling driver by default? Check via `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`. If yes, that would be the reason the old way doesn't work, at least I think. But I don't know the AMD driver way.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thank you for the reply. The output (for cpu 0 - 15) is amd-pstate, so it does sound like it. Unfortunately I don't know what the output of that cmd was when I was on 21.04. So now I guess I need to find a way to disable it?

Comment: To answer my own question on how to disable it, I have not found a way to disable just boost but rather to disable the amd_pstate scaling driver, by adding initcall_blacklist=amd_pstate_init in grub. The output of the above command is now 'acpi-cpufreq'. So it's not fully a solution as I guess there are upsides to using the new driver, but it'll have to do for now.

Comment: Yes, `acpi-cpufreq` would have been the default CPU frequency scaling driver before, as you have discovered.